# How to make DB call and MQ call work together or fail together

Tags: java, web-services

I have one design issue.

Current code first makes call to DB, saves the message and immediately there a call for MQ for placing the message in to PutQueue method. both these calls returning void.

I am using database and Mq to save my transaction. current code first saves the message to DB and next puts the message to MQ and this mq places the message to Omni process.

In production I have scenario  where message is saved to DB and MQ is not getting placed due to some error.In such case my message getting saved to DB not in Omni process. I would like to change my design such way that either it should fail or success.

For doing DB call I am consuming another service which simply returns void in save call. same thing in Message MQ as well. How can I make both work together or fail together.

Please let me know if my question is incomplete and missed any key points.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is alright you could commit database and MQ. Otherwise, rollback or do nothing. What database are you using? You could write stored procedure that your Java program calls. That procedure could do all the work...your MQ method can also return some value that indicates whether there was error or not. Then you could delete last message from database if there was error..there are plenty of solutions.

EDIT: sorry I misplaced Oracle AQ and IBM MQ when I wrote that you can write stored procedure...you can't do that. But you can do other things I wrote.

Comment: It is ibm mq and oracle database. For doing save we are calling stored procedure using jar file. As per you suggestion what i can do is first execute mq based on its response i can do save. Here the issue is i should be able rollback mq incase of db failure.